# Error Installing Content Manager IBM Connections 4.5

Tags: oracle11g, ibm-connections

I'm trying to install IBM Connections 4.5 on Oracle 11.2, but I'm having a problem with only 'Content Manager'. After Install process, the IBM Installation Manager appears this summary:

Install results : 
CLFRP0038E: IBM Connections Content Manager failed to be configured on WebSphere Application Server. Error Step : Step "action-config-ce-ccm"

** One or more components failed installation. Please review. **

---

And in ConfigTrace log file appear this error:

config-ce-applicationserver-xml-config:
Target finished: config-ce-applicationserver-xml-config
Target started: config-ce-configurebootstrap-xml-config
c
Target finished: c
     [echo] ... generating CCM Content Engine profile completed
     [echo] Running Content Engine configuration tasks
     [exec] There was an error executing the Configure GCD JDBC Data Sources task.
     [exec] Running the task failed with the following message: The data source configuration failed: 
     [exec] WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node svconnectionsCellManager01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
     [exec] testing Database connection
     [exec] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "E:/IBM/Connections/addons/ccm/ContentEngine/tools/configure/tmp/configurejdbcgcd.tcl"; exception information: javax.management.MBeanException
     [exec] c: DSRA8000E: Java archive (JAR) or compressed files do not exist in the path or the required access is not allowed.  Path: E:/app/Administrator/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar

The 'ojdbc6.jar' exist on the path, but the application report this error.

What can be this question?

Thanks

Comment: it's most likely in the WebSphere Application Server path. You'll want to look at the WebSphere Variables in the Admin Console.

Comment: I checked in websphere variables and the 'ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH' has the value= E:/app/Administrator/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/lib

Comment: This path is of oracle 11.2.0.3 installation that contents the jdbc files.

Comment: then you might want to look at the jvm / java process settings and determine if you want to set it there on the path.  it sounds like it's just not picking up the path in either the script or the websphere instance. (If this doesn't work open a Support request with IBM)

Comment: Is the any rule for JDBC path on websphere? On my environment all applications (wikis, files, actitities, etc...) are installed normally and are with JDBC set for the same path. My problem is with only Content Manager.

Comment: you still might want to look at this http://questionscollection.tumblr.com/post/75968145589/c2070-587-exams-vce-certification-simulator  it looks like a common issue with p8, and may apply here

Comment: I see the question, but the database is Oracle 11.2.0.3

Comment: it should open a support request with IBM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that KSH is installed?  I have seen these errors on linux systems if the korne shell is not installed on the system.  It is documented that CCM requires KSH but most people miss that part of the requirements.

Comment: My environment is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with Oracle 11.2.0.3 and IBM Connections 4.5

Comment: My question is only Content Manager. Others applications (Wikis, Activities, files, etc..) were installed normally.

Comment: Did you run the install as administrator? When you launch installation manager right click on the icon and choose run as administrator